# Split Column values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I split the values of a column based on conditions in Pandas?
I want to get the column B to be transformed to the first split before the point(.) if the value in A is smaller than 5
For example, I have the following table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | ABC.DEF |
| 2 | ABC.DEF |
| 8 | ABC.DEF |
| 8 | ABC.DEF |

It should change to

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | ABC |
| 2 | ABC |
| 8 | ABC.DEF |
| 8 | ABC.DEF |

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
m=df['A'].lt(5)
#your condition
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[m,'B']=df.loc[m,'B'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

OR

```
#import numpy as np
df['B']=np.where(m,df['B'].str.split('.').str[0],df['B'])
```

Output of `df`:

```
    A   B
0   2   ABC
1   2   ABC
2   8   ABC.DEF
3   8   ABC.DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), that replaces original values with the ones provided as second argument where the condition (provided as first argument) is `False`:

```py
df.B.where(df.A.ge(5), df.B.str.split('.').str[0], inplace=True)
```

`df` will be turned into:

```sh
   A        B
0  2      ABC
1  2      ABC
2  8  ABC.DEF
3  8  ABC.DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
df.loc[df.A<5, 'B']=df.loc[df.A<5, 'B'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A        B
0  2      ABC
1  2      ABC
2  8  ABC.DEF
3  8  ABC.DEF
```